# Using a .bat file to run a .exe directed towards a specific .cmm file and have it ask me for the name of the output .cmm file?

Tags: batch-file

```
start /d "C:\UPAPPS\XPloder\pmvsmooth" loess.exe filename filename
```

This is what I've got currently - it will function just as I need, however I'd like it to prompt me as to what to title that last filename

Comment: Hi Ahowse75, I see you are new here.  You will have a much better chance of having your question answered (and not downvoted), if your question is more precise. I had to read this a few times to understand that your question has nothing to do with .cmm files (whatever that is), but is really a straight-up DOS/Windows batch file question -- "How do I prompt the user for a variable before running a command and using that variable"?

Comment: Thanks wheezil, I removed the .cmm info all together. but yes, essentially I need the .bat file to prompt the user for a filename variable

Comment: Open a Command Prompt, type `Set /?`, press the enter key and read the usage information, _(with special attention to the `/P` option)_.